# How to add a constant custom object in JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am working on a project and I came across the following JSON Schema, which has a custom object ("ory.sh/kratos"). What is it? Is it a constant object that should be added to every JSON in order to validate this schema?

```
{
  "$id": "https://schemas.ory.sh/presets/kratos/quickstart/email-password/identity.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "traits": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "email",
          "title": "E-Mail",
          "minLength": 3,
---------------------------------------------------------
          "ory.sh/kratos": {
            "credentials": {
              "password": {
                "identifier": true
              }
            },
            "verification": {
              "via": "email"
            },
            "recovery": {
              "via": "email"
            }
          }
---------------------------------------------------------
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "first": {
              "title": "First Name",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "last": {
              "title": "Last Name",
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "email"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not ask the schema author?  I'm sure they have a support channel if they are publishing their schemas for external use.